# WP-Minify 400 errors and open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: plugins

i've been having a world of difficulty w/ the WP-minify plugin.  usually i get 400/bad request errors when i try to access the combined/minified script or style files.  this tends to break the entire look of my site. but on my last site i came across a new error... when i try to view the combined script i see the following warning/errors followed by a bunch of gibberish.

anybody know what the heck this is about?

`

**Warning**:  is_file() [function.is-file]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/kathyi/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/cache//minify_2fac368eb244a71e24b5c8bb929e8107.gz) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/soulmatesummit.net/httpdocs:/tmp) in **/var/www/vhosts/soulmatesummit.net/httpdocs/online-course/wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/min/lib/Minify/Cache/File.php** on line **71**

**Warning**:  is_file() [function.is-file]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/kathyi/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/cache//minify_2fac368eb244a71e24b5c8bb929e8107) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/soulmatesummit.net/httpdocs:/tmp) in **/var/www/vhosts/soulmatesummit.net/httpdocs/online-course/wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/min/lib/Minify/Cache/File.php** on line **33**

**Warning**:  is_file() [function.is-file]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/kathyi/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/cache//minify_2fac368eb244a71e24b5c8bb929e8107.gz) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/mysite.net/httpdocs:/tmp) in **/var/www/vhosts/mysite.net/httpdocs/online-course/wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/min/lib/Minify/Cache/File.php** on line **33**

**Warning**:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/vhosts/mysite.net/httpdocs/online-course/wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/min/lib/Minify/Cache/File.php:71) in **/var/www/vhosts/soulmatesummit.net/httpdocs/online-course/wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/min/lib/Minify.php** on line **312**

`

Comment: why don't you [minify](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) your javascript yourself ?

Comment: b/c it is easier to keep all my files separate for editing and then combine them all on-the-fly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"open_basedir restriction in effect" errors mean the host is very restrictive in terms of php configs. The open_basedir setting prevents scripts from reading files (via requires, includes, any of the file handing functions, etc.) from directories that are not marked as "safe." It was designed to prevent users from accessing sensitive files and/or other user's files shared servers while PHP was running as "nobody."

If you have Cpanel or Plesk, etc., try switching to the CGI version of PHP using suPHP. But if you can't, find a new host.

Comment: ahh that makes sense. i have had a lot of issues w/ permissions w/ this host.  not my choice of host and i probably have no say in who they company uses, "i just work here"